# How to automaticaly assign network settings for dhcp server own interface with dnsmasq?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, dhcp, dnsmasq

Is it possible to configure network interface via the DHCP server hosted on the same machine?

Currently, I have next records in my /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

Also, dnsmasq listening to enp0s8.

But I can't achieve the desired effect that way.
(OS: Ubuntu server 16)

**UPD 1**

I'm configuring a virtual network for educational purposes.
So, it is just an interest: how to touch as less files as possible while configuration? And is it possible to make dnsmasq to handle that case?

My topology:

I have a central node with the dnsmasq and some other nodes in the same network. Central node has two interfaces:

- enp03 which faces the host network. It configured by host network
  DHCP and has a dynamic IP address.
- enp08 which faces the virtual network. dnsmasq is listening this interfase.

Now, if have the next central node configuration:

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp03 
iface enp03 inet auto

auto enp08
iface enp08 inet static
 address 10.0.5.15
```

**/etc/dnsmasq.conf**

```
interface=enp0s8
dhcp-range=10.0.5.0,10.0.5.100
```

The problem starts if I make a mistake and assign some static IP for enp0s8 out of the dhcp-range.
So now I have to maintain the consistency between /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/dnsmasq.conf

Comment: The way I understand the question, which doesn't make sense to me, is that you're trying to setup a router that would use a dynamic IP address.  If that's the case, you should explain why you need to do something like that, hoping that we can offer a better approach.

Comment: @JuliePelletier The question can be interpreted to make sense, because the DHCP server can serve a fixed IP to, erm, the host itself when it tries to get one. It is possible that it can't be made to work because a broadcast packet might not sent back to the port it came in on by an Ethernet switch (i.e., does the sending host of a broadcast packet ever see it incoming?). I don't really know the details.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel:  I was pushing to get details but OP doesn't seem available to provide them.

Comment: The question updatet.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible that the host which the DHCP server is running on can get an IP address from that DHCP server, to assign a IP address to itself. If you are worried about assigning static IP addresses to your DHCP range, shorten your DHCP range to `10.0.5.11,10.0.5.100` and you can use the first 10 IP addresses for static assignments.